# styling react-select component using tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, react-select

I'm working on a project using react, tailwindcss and the react package react-select.

What I want to achieve:

The user can select from a select input field. If however, the select input field does not have a fitting option the user can manually type the answer.

For this I am using `<CreatableSelect />`.

All other input fields are styled using tailwind, which looks like this:

```
input, textarea, select {
  background-color: #f7fafc;

  @apply text-sm border-2 border-gray-200
  rounded-sm px-4 py-2.5 text-gray-800 tracking-wide focus-visible:outline-white
  focus:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-green-500 focus-visible:ring-offset-2
  transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out;
}
```

the react component I am using looks like this:

```
export default function TypeaheadSelect() {
  const values = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Netflix' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Amazon Prime' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Hulu' },
    { id: 4, name: 'HBO' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Disney+' },
  ];

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  const companyOptions = values.map(c => ({ value: c.id, label: c.name }));

  const handleChange = selectedOption => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
    console.log(`Selected Option: ${selectedOption.label}`);
  };

  const styles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      backgroundColor: '#f7fafc',
    }),
    option: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      color: '#2d3748',
      backgroundColor: '#f7fafc',
    }),
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CreatableSelect
        className="customInput"
        options={companyOptions}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={selectedOption}
        styles={styles}
      />

    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a neat way to apply the css looks and haptics from input, textarea and select to the CreatableSelect?

Here's what it looks so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are 2 main way to styled react-select component.

1. Using `classNames` props
2. Using `components` props

### Using `className` props

Combine with `unstyled` props checkout this stories =>
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/storybook/stories/UnstyledWithTailwind.stories.tsx

Note that even with `unstyled` there are still some css left that can't be replace.

### Using `components` props

This will replace the entire component.

Checkout this stories => https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/storybook/stories/CustomInput.stories.tsx

To find out which component to replace checkout this render method.

[packages/react-select/src/Select.tsx](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/06e34882638d1526b9f5a1238bb567a3e9460ce5/packages/react-select/src/Select.tsx#L2193-L2240)